# how to display below JSON in a table using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

```
{  
   "ldoc":{  
      "SOLD":{  
         "range":{  
            "1 - 2":0,
            "No LDOC":2,
            "0 - 0":0,
            "8 - 14":1,
            "15+":2,
            "3 - 7":7
         }
      },
      "STOCK":{  
         "range":{  
            "1 - 2":0,
            "No LDOC":2,
            "0 - 0":0,
            "8 - 14":20,
            "15+":13,
            "3 - 7":6
         }
      }
   }
}
```

how to display this data in a table format using angular js .Please give me some approach.This data is dynamic.

Comment: show your code(effort) first we are here to help you :-)

Comment: Posible duplicate from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478066/how-to-display-below-json-in-table-format-using-angularjs)

Comment: A tip: you may have to apply some transformations on the data before feeding it to the view; I'd recommend implementing some function that would generate either a bidimensional array or an array of flat objects from this structure; that should be easier to turn into a table; if you need to make it editable, though, it would need a slightly more complex approach..

Comment: I get this data ffrom spring rest services .I cant change the data format ! So , is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xspd7g/1/)
That's how you can display data in the table.

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="Main">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>SOLD</th>
                <th>STOCK</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["1 - 2"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["1 - 2"]}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["No LDOC"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["No LDOC"]}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["0 - 0"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["0 - 0"]}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["8 - 14"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["8 - 14"]}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["15+"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["15+"]}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.SOLD.range["3 - 7"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{jsonObject.ldoc.STOCK.range["3 - 7"]}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your Angular app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('Main', function($scope){
        $scope.jsonObject = {  
           "ldoc":{  
              "SOLD":{  
                 "range":{  
                    "1 - 2":0,
                    "No LDOC":2,
                    "0 - 0":0,
                    "8 - 14":1,
                    "15+":2,
                    "3 - 7":7
                 }
              },
              "STOCK":{  
                 "range":{  
                    "1 - 2":0,
                    "No LDOC":2,
                    "0 - 0":0,
                    "8 - 14":20,
                    "15+":13,
                    "3 - 7":6
                 }
              }
           }
        };

    });
```